# In Vedic astrology, why is Shani called karma phal data when all the planets are also giving fruits of karma only?

Tags: astrology, navagraha, shani

In vedic astrology, 'Grahas' are supposed to give us fruits of prarabdh karma but for some reason Shani is said to be deliver us fair fruits of karma. Why is emphasis put on Shani specifically when other Grahas are doing same thing?

Answer (score -1):

- Shanaischara rules the 10th Bhaava of Karma
- There are two types (or rather, meanings) of Karma
  1 Any form (walking, hitting, talking, thinking)
  2 Work
- Shanideva, in particular is responsible for giving the result of **work**
- For this purpose, he also rules the 11th Bhaava of आय (income/gain/benefit) or lack thereof.
- Although all Grahas give Karma Phala, Shaniaschara is Kaaraka of Karma (of all Grahas), meaning, it happens under his jurisdiction/view/approval/understanding, even if he's not the one giving you the results (on the surface).

This Kaaraka nature is used to signify the nature of Karma itself.
Karma is like Shanaischara (who himself is like Surya), it doesn't
care about your feelings. If something good is destined, it will
happen even if it emotionally or mentally ruins you due to arrogance
or greed or whatever. Similarly, the bad will also happen, even if it
ruins you due to depression or anxiety.

It's a bit like how you cannot plead with Surya to rise one minute later, or even one second. He doesn't care. Similar natures have gotten onto his son (Shaniashchara). Yama also has a similar nature due to the same reason. The exact nature has also gone into Karma. Think of Karma itself like being a partial extraction or a mini version of Shanischara. That's what Kaaraka means, Shanaischara 'causes' or operates Karma (among other things).

You can think of him like a driver of a car. Even though the 'master' temporarily may be Brhaspati or Chandra, there's only one way the car drives, according to nature of Shanaischara. IT MAY be going into a temple, or to a nice relaxing place, according to the wishes of the master, but it goes in one manner, due to the nature of the driver. Of course, his full nature only expresses when there's no one except him in the car, or to a smaller extent, when he is the master (appropriate Dasha).

Comment: where is the reference man? you have to give references from authentic Vedic astrology canonical texts like brihat parasara hora sastra, phaladeepika etc.

Comment: You'll have to read the book to find the 'reference'. What you're asking for is reference from a published scholar, essentially. Because, these things aren't connected in texts.

For example, the 10th and 11th Bhaava of Karma and Aaya, in the Naisargika situation are ruled by Shanaischara who rules the 10th and 11th Raashi (Makara and Kumbha).

Now, how exactly will I reference that? Because no where is it said that the 10th raashi and the 10th Bhaava is connected (because it's assumed anyone reading the texts can naturally figure it out). I must point out, that your expectation is flawed.

Comment: The 'reference's that you refer to, it is not possible for them to exist, because of the nature of the text. Even if something is accepted by all Jyotishis, it won't be in the text. Because, the text is not for any random person reading it once in 30 minutes, it's meant to be studied for years. @AmritenduMukhopadhyay